# PHPBB3 group leader ontop on external page

Tags: php, html, phpbb3

I am trying to display the group members and group leader from phpbb3 on an external page. I can successfully display all the members, but instead I want the group leader on top just like the phpbb3 group list shows or the user name in bold, preferably the first one.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
$sql = "SELECT phpbb_users.user_id, phpbb_user_group.group_id, phpbb_users.username, phpbb_profile_fields_data.pf_country, phpbb_profile_fields_data.pf_class  FROM phpbb_users, phpbb_profile_fields_data, phpbb_user_group WHERE phpbb_user_group.group_id IN(23) AND phpbb_users.user_id = phpbb_profile_fields_data.user_id AND phpbb_users.user_id = phpbb_user_group.user_id ORDER BY phpbb_users.username";
```

After that I am kind of unsure what do to do because If I include group leader in there it will only filter group leader and not the entire group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query:

`$sql = "SELECT phpbb_users.user_id, phpbb_user_group.group_id, phpbb_users.username, phpbb_profile_fields_data.pf_country, phpbb_profile_fields_data.pf_class, phpbb_user_group.group_leader  FROM phpbb_users, phpbb_profile_fields_data, phpbb_user_group WHERE phpbb_user_group.group_id IN(23) AND phpbb_users.user_id = phpbb_profile_fields_data.user_id AND phpbb_users.user_id = phpbb_user_group.user_id ORDER BY group_leader, phpbb_users.username";`

This will add one more column to the end of your list: `phpbb_user_group.group_leader` and order by that column and then `username`. If this column contains a `1`, they are a group leader. If it contains a `0` they are just a regular group member.

Sample output:

```
+---------+----------+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| user_id | group_id | username       | pf_country   | pf_class     | group_leader |
+---------+----------+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|     123 |       23 | Person 3       |           US |           12 |            1 |
|     543 |       23 | Person 1       |           UK |           13 |            0 |
|     714 |       23 | Person 2       |           DE |           01 |            0 |
+---------+----------+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Ah I didn't even think it would be this simple.. So silly of me. but when ORDER BY, shouldn't it also be "phpbb_user_group.group_leader" instead of just "group_leader"?

Comment: You can use the table prefix, but since non of the other tables you are querying have a column named `group_leader`, it wasn't needed.